# SIGSEGV in Android 2.1 WebView

Tags: android

I am intermittently getting a SIGSEGV when using a WebView in Android 2.1. 
The SIGSEGV is inside /system/lib/libwebcore.so .

Is there a known problem with this WebView implementation that I could work around with to avoid the SEGV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGSEGV` indicates a crash in native code. Assuming that you are not using the NDK, then the native code will be the firmware.

If you can reproduce this error on multiple Android devices, or in the emulator, create a sample project that generates the crash and [post it as an issue](http://b.android.com) if it is not already out there. If you only see this on one specific device, contact that device manufacturer, if possible.

However, there is no workaround for a `SIGSEGV`, other than to try to determine what in your Web content or Java code triggers it and to get rid of that content or code.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there is no NDK code here. For "to try to determine what in your Web content or Java code triggers it and to get rid of that content or code." - is it possible to see what Java code triggered it? The dump for the SIGSEGV does not have a Java trace.

Comment: @mparaz: "is it possible to see what Java code triggered it?" -- not as far as I know. You probably are not using `WebView` all that many places, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare: can SIGSEGV signal cause application to force close by the system?  it does not throw any exception.

Comment: @TalKanel: A SIGSEGV won't "force close", in that I don't think it brings up a dialog box. A SIGSEGV should cause your app to just kinda vanish, AFAIK. Other than the SIGSEGV report, there will be nothing else in LogCat IIRC.