# Why do I get a SIGSEGV on Android when using a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SIGSEGV in Android 2.1 WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897744/sigsegv-in-android-2-1-webview)

My app crashes when the WebView appears to be trying to load something (the page usually has already loaded something and is displaying it).

I get the following output on log cat...

It seems to happen after the Garbage Collector is run...

10-14 14:43:45.451: D/dalvikvm(27679): GC_CONCURRENT freed 827K, 16% free 8966K/10567K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 74ms

10-09 10:52:36.428: A/libc(19260): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 19311 (FP_DoPlay)

Any idea how to investigate this?

Comment: This is all logcat says... 10-09 10:52:36.428: A/libc(19260): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 19311 (FP_DoPlay)

Comment: I'm running on a Asus TF 201 with android 4.1.1 and I'll try to reproduce it in the emulator although I tend to avoid the emulator.